# How to add checkbox group outside html form to model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

I have this code

**Razor**

```
@foreach (SFD.Models.General.List.Customer item in Model.CustomerList)
{
  <tr id="@item.CustomerId">
    <td>@Html.CheckBox("CustomerId["+@item.CustomerId+"]")</td>
    ...
  </tr>
}
```

which generate html output

```
<input name="CustomerId[22394]" id="CustomerId_22394_" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="CustomerId[22394]" type="hidden" value="false">
```

the problem I need to solve is that checkbox group is outside form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Customer", FormMethod.Post }))
{
...
}
```

and therefore checkbox group values are not send after submit value. So my question is, how I can add these values to the submit request ? Maybe with jQuery onclick event ? What datatype property for checkbox group is suitable, it is for example an array ?

```
public int[] CustomerId;
```

but how to check if the value is true or false from that array, maybe list of CheckBoxClass is better, but how to bind and checkbox to that list, or only true values are presented ?

Comment: Inputs with `name="CustomerId[22394]"` could never bind (the indexers need to be zero-based and consecutive if provided) but you could bind to `int[] CustomerId` if you change all of them to `name="CustomerId"`. And do not use `CheckBox()` which is for binding to a `bool` property and creates and associated hidden input with `value="false"` which would cause binding to fail. Why can they not be inside the `<form>` tags?

Comment: I need to get bool property with Id value of customer, and it is outside of the form because the whole submit form is generated by ajax and the checkboxlist is generated from different form submit, it can be done somehow but it seems to me complicated right now therefore I want to assign the checkbox group via jquery submit event

Comment: You view code will never_get bool property with Id value of customer_ (and you binding to `int[]`, not `bool` anyway). To bind to that property, you would need `<input name="CustomerId" type="checkbox" value="@item.CustomerId" />` inside your loop.

Comment: It seems that Html helper does not provide method for this input syntax, so I will try it manually in html

Comment: Yes, you need to create it manually (the `CheckBox()` and `CheckBoxFor()` methods are for binding to `bool` properties). And you can give the checkbox a `form="xxx"` attribute and modify your `BeginForm()` method to add an `id="xxx"` attribute (but its still not clear why you think you need to render this outside the `<form>` tags

Comment: I tried `<input name="CustomerId" type="checkbox" value="@item.CustomerId" form="customerForm" />` and `@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Customer", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "customerForm" }))` but I don't see that variable in the `Request.Form collection` :/ its hard to explain but I have more forms on the page and I need to use the checkboxes for both forms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124203/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-muflix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HTML5 `form` attribute to associate form controls that are placed outside with that form, for example

```
<form id="myForm .... >
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<input type="text" form="myForm" />
```

Note this is not supported in older browsers.

However the form controls your generating cannot bind to a property which is `int[] CustomerId`. First, your generating `name` attributes with non-zero, no-consecutive indexers, and second, your inputs are posting either `CustomerId[22394]=true&CustomerId[22394]=false` if the the checkbox is checked, or just `CustomerId[22394]=false` if its not, which cannot be bound to `int`.

You can create your checkboxes manually inside your loop (note that because your property is a simple collection, you do not need an indexer)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Customer", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "customerForm" }))
{
    ...
}

@foreach (var item in Model.CustomerList)
{
  <tr>
    <td><input name="CustomerId" value="@item.CustomerId" form="customerForm" type="checkbox" /></td>
    ... 
  </tr>
}
```

A better solution is to use a view model that includes a (say) `bool IsSelected` property so that you can use the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods and your view would be

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.CustomerList.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerList[i].CustomerId, new { form = "customerForm" })
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CustomerList[i].IsSelected, new { form = "customerForm" })
}
```

and post back to a method that accepts the same model that you used in the view.